# How to color keyword in tkinter in vs code

Tags: tkinter, visual-studio-code, colors, keyword

The left section is a lecture from YouTube and the right section is vs code I am using.

I wanted to change the color of some keywords such as `Tk`, `Label`, `pack()`, and `mainloop()` like the left section.

Normally, themes automatically change colors of things, but when I tried to use tkinter module, vs code didn't automatically change the colors.

Searching results from google were all about questions related to widgets color change and syntax or semantic color change.

[image]

Comment: The left one is [sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com) text ide and you are using vscode so there are different. However, you can change vscode theme to get a similar look. [Here is something I found that might be useful for you.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.sublime-keybindings)

Comment: @Saad Amazing way of solving the issue. I didn't come up with that idea. Thanks a lot. I will try it now

Comment: it seems to be focusing on keybindings haha

Answer (score 0):

I found the pretty simple solution.

If you install sublime theme in vs code extension, keywords of tkinter will be colored.

Great !